# Rails 4 (Mongoid): Getting relation document `_id` from `after_initialize` callback of embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have two models, parent (store) and child (asset), I need to get the store `_id` from `after_initialize` callback of embedded asset.

```
class Store
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :assets
end


class Asset
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :store

  after_initialize :get_store_id

  def get_store_id
    logger.info self.store
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

The logger print `nil`, the question is how can I get the related store document?

Comment: What is your question or problem? Does your code raise an error? What is the message? How do you use your code, how do you create a store and its assets?

Comment: I edited the question:
"The logger print `nil`, the question is how can I get the related store document?"

Comment: Show the statements you execute.